# webapps logging in azure

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have a Python application which is hosted in Azure Web Apps using Flask API. I'm using the Logging module of Python to log errors in the application as below.

```
import logging
logging.info("value").
```

But logs are not formed in Application Insights. However, print outs *are* logged in Application Insights.

Is there any configuration required from Application Insights for logging purpose?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any configuration required from Application Insights for logging purpose?

Microsoft's supported solution for tracking and exporting data for your Python applications is through the Opencensus Python SDK  via the Azure Monitor exporters.

Below is the sample code to pass the connection string into the exporter

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# TODO: replace the all-zero GUID with your instrumentation key.
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)

def valuePrompt():
    line = input("Enter a value: ")
    logger.warning(line)

def main():
    while True:
        valuePrompt()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Steps to be followed for logs in Application Insights**

1. Generate some local log data
2. The code will ask value to be entered continuously and a log will be emitted for every value entered.
3. Need to pass the connection string directly into the exporter.
4. The exporter sends log data to Azure Monitor.
5. You can also add the custom messages to your log messages.

For further information check the [Application Insights logs for Python application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#logs).